# Regex with Java, multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I have a series of blocks that match this format

```
724280 141105/1300 1022.90 992.20 8.44 282.80 0.00 51.00
0.00 0.00 284.70 100.00 0.00 100.00
0.00 0.80 0.90 0.00 0.01 7.94
5.81 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 11.10
-8.70 39.40 -0.02 999.00 471.90 20.00
5.68
```

What's the regular expression I would use to find these blocks (there are normally about 84 of them within a document)?

to clarify:
It's a six line block

```
Integer Integer"/"Integer Double Double Double Double Double Double
Double Double Double Double Double Double
Double Double Double Double Double Double
Double Double Double Double Double Double
Double Double Double Double Double Double
Double
```

Comment: could you clarify what's `this format`? a bunch of numbers could be a format of anything. and in what aspect you feel like to solve this problem using regex?

Comment: @ HuStmpHrrr a regular expression that could find that exact block within a larger file

Comment: If you want to find "that exact block", this regex should do it: `"724280 141105/1300 1022\\.90 992\\.20 8\\.44 282\\.80 0\\.00 51\\.00........"` and so on.  If you want to find blocks that are similar but not exactly this, _you will need to develop the criteria to describe what you're looking for_.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: @ajb edited the question to provide details on the block. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am beginner. May be like this:
`-?\d+\s+-?\d+\/-?\d+\s+(-?\d+\.\d+(\s+)?){31}`

**Description**:

`-?\d+` - integer

`\s+` - spaces

`-?\d+\/-?\d+` - integer like int/int

`\s+` - spaces

`(-?\d+\.\d+(\s+)?){31}` - 31 doubles

Comment: `(\s+)?` means "optionally one or more whitespaces", so it could be simplified to `\s*`.  However, simply `\s+` is probably better anyway, since there should be whitespace between each double (a "newline" counts as whitespace), except that it may fail on the last `double` in the file.